# How to find the area of the surface enclosed between a sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=4a^2$ and a cylinder $x^2+(y-a)^2=a^2$?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

> Find the area of the surface enclosed between a sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=4a^2$ and a cylinder $x^2+(y-a)^2=a^2$. The correct answer should be $(8\pi-16)a^2$.

This is an illustration:

[image]

First, there's the following formula to calculate surface area:
$$
\int\int_R\sqrt{Z_x^2+Z_y^2+1}\cdot dA
$$
In our case it's:
$$
\int\int_R \sqrt{\frac{x^2+y^2}{4a^2-x^2-y^2}+1}dA
$$
We can move into polar coordinates (and multiply the original operand by $r$ as the Jacobian in polar), then:
$$
\int\int_R\ r\sqrt{\frac{r^2}{4a^2-r^2}+1}drd\theta
$$
Now the only thing left is to find the bounds of $r$ and $\theta$.

The projection of the surface to $xy$ plane will be a circle with the center in $(0,a)$ with the radius $a$ so it's symmetric around $y$ axis. Then $0\le\theta\le\pi$.

Because $x^2+y^2=2ay$ then $r=2a\sin\theta$, therefore we now have the integral:
$$
\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{2a\sin\theta}r\sqrt{\frac{r^2}{4a^2-r^2}+1}drd\theta
$$

And this is where I'm stuck. How can I integrate $dr$?

Comment: Are you said it have to be calculated with the parametrisation in cartesian? In spherical is simpler.

Comment: @RafaBudría I can use spherical coordinates as well, but I'm not sure how spherical coordinates work in double integrals we only used spherical with triple integrals

Comment: They work fine, too. I've answered a similar question and it gives you clues about the subtlities involved. Even correcting the factor $2a$ DonAntonio missed (see comment), it doesn't result in the given answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2296579/362604

Comment: @RafaBudría do you have a link to the similar question?

Comment: You see it now...

Comment: I tried getting some insights but I'd need to study over this in order to understand all the intricacies. In addition this is beyond the curriculum in my course. All of the problems relating to finding the area are solved in our course by finding an element of surface using the the formula $\sqrt{Z_x^2+Z_y^2+1}$ so I'm wondering what I did wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59713/discussion-between-rafa-budria-and-yos).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some chat and subsequent corrections, all is clear now. Continuing from the end of the question,

$$S/2=\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{2a\sin\theta}r\sqrt{\dfrac{r^2}{4a^2-r^2}+1}drd\theta=$$

$$=\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{2a\sin\theta}\frac {2ar}{\sqrt{4a^2-r^2}}drd\theta=2a\int_0^{\pi}\left(-\sqrt{4a^2-4a^2\sin^2\theta}+2a\right)d\theta=$$

$$=4a^2\int_0^\pi(-\vert\cos\theta\vert+1)d\theta=4a^2(\pi-2)$$

This is the area of the upper part, but upper and lower are symmetric, so,

$S=a^2(8\pi-16)$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{r^2}{4a^2-r^2}+1=\frac{r^2+4a^2-r^2}{4a^2-r^2}\implies r\sqrt{\frac{r^2}{4a^2-r^2}+1}=\frac r{\sqrt{4a^2-r^2}}\implies$$

$$\left.\int_0^{2a\sin\theta}\frac r{\sqrt{4a^2-r^2}}dr=-\sqrt{4a^2-r^2}\right|_0^{2a\sin\theta}=-\sqrt{4a^2-4a^2\sin^2\theta}+2a=-2a\cos\theta+2a$$

and etc. Yet I think the final answer is different from what you said it is...

Comment: It is different. What did I do wrong?

Comment: I shall try to check that a little later.

Comment: It must be $\dfrac{2ar}{\sqrt{4a^2-r^2}}$, leading to $4a^2(1-\cos\theta)$, but it don't work either.